# Tips of umbrella tree are turning black

Tags: houseplants

the tips of our umbrella tree are turning black – any ideas? It seems to be mostly at the top of the plant and starting from the tips moving inward

[image: umbrella tree]

Answer (score 1):

Blackened tips of leaves usually mean fertilizer burn; so, that's my guess. Umbrella trees can be sensitive to nitrogen fertilizers.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are good that the cause is overwatering but to do a good diagnosis check for these:

- look on the underside of the leaves and at the base of the stems for mealybug which looks like cotton fluff or scale which are brown bumps
- consider the amount of light the plant receives.  This plant should be in a bright location, preferably south facing.  If it is not right up against a window move it to get better light
- consider your watering schedule.  Plants in low light can easily go two weeks without watering.  When you do water add enough so it flows out the bottom then let at least the top inch of soil dry before watering again